# Get All data From API

Tags: javascript, json, api

I just want to print all the data from the `API`. I get the `JSON's` data from [calendarific](https://calendarific.com/). I am only able to print specific data but what can I do to print all the data? Here is  what I tried

```
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  newRequest.open('GET', 'https://calendarific.com/api/v2/holidays?&api_key=<myKey>&country=US&year=2019')
  newRequest.onload = function() {
    var ourData = JSON.parse(newRequest.responseText);
    // para.innerHTML = ourData.response.holidays[407].name
    //  console.log(ourData.response.holidays[407].name)
    renderHTML(ourData)
  }
  newRequest.send();

});

function renderHTML(data) {
  var htmlString = '';

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    htmlString += '<p>' + data[i].response.holidays[0].name + '</p>'

  }
  //i want to show inside paragraph whose id is para
  para.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', htmlString)
}
```

I just tried the `For` loop may be Problem is in inside `For loop`?

Comment: Please add `console.log( ourData )` and post in the code also.

Comment: `console.log( ourData )` prints the `JSON`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can print all the holiday's name by updating the `for` loop inside `renderHTML` function like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.response.holidays.length; i ++) {
     htmlString += '<p>' + data.response.holidays[i].name + '</p>'
}
```

because format returned from API is like:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "code": 200
    },
    "response": {
        "holidays": [
            {
                "name": "Name of holiday goes here",
                "description": "Description of holiday goes here",
                "date": {
                    "iso": "2018-12-31",
                    "datetime": {
                        "year": 2018,
                        "month": 12,
                        "day": 31
                    }
                },
                "type": [
                    "Type of Observance goes here"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, `data` is not actually an array here. It is the `data.response.holidays` which is an array and we need to loop over it to get all the details.